# C++: values of pointers are wrong after return

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

**Edit** changed code to be a minimal reproducible example

So Im basically having a struct and a function that creates instances of this struct, pushes them into a `std::vector<Node>` and then returns it.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


struct Node {
    int value;
    Node *left;
    Node *right;
};

Node createNodeFamily(Node child1, Node child2) {

    Node parent;
    parent.value = child1.value + child2.value;

    parent.left = &child1;
    parent.right = &child2;

    return parent;
}

std::vector<Node> f(std::vector<Node>& nodes) {
    std::vector<Node> l;
    Node parent = createNodeFamily(nodes[0], nodes[1]);
    l.push_back(parent);

    Node r = l[0];
    std::cout << "correct value of left child node: " << r.left->value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "correct value of right child node: " << r.right->value << std::endl;

    return l;
}


int main() {

    Node child1;
    child1.value = 2;

    Node child2;
    child2.value = 1;

    std::vector<Node> children;
    children.push_back(child1);
    children.push_back(child2);

    std::vector<Node> p = f(children);

    Node parent = p[0];
    //std::cout << parent.value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "wrong value of left child node: " << parent.left->value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "wrong value of right child node: " << parent.right->value << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

The output in my case:

```
Printed inside the function:
>> correct value of left child node: 2
>> correct value of right child node: 1
Printed outside the function:
>> wrong value of left child node: 1875944288
>> wrong value of right child node: 16717313
```

So the struct has the two attributes `left` and `right` which are pointers that point to a address of a child Node. When Im reading the values of those pointera printing them inside the `testFunction` they are correct.
But when I return them, and print them they are holding seemingly random numbers.

Comment: Are the nodes in your vector pointing to other nodes in your vector?  If so, you're going to need to rethink your design.  Every time you call `push_back` on a vector it can invalidate all references, pointers, and iterators to all elements in the vector, which would break your node linking.

Comment: ... and if that's the only problem, you could perhaps overcome it by using a `std::list` instead.

Comment: I dont think thats the problem, because I because the content of the vector is correct when Im checking inside the function /before returning). I think the problem is that when the function stops the values of the pointers are pointing to stop existing and therefore when reading them give random results @NathanOliver

Comment: ... or by using the `reserve` method with some kind of maximum size (if there is one which isn't nonsensical), to hinder `push_back` from reallocating the vector.

Comment: @TheodorPeifer Can we get a [mre] so we can copy and paste the code into our own compiler(s)?

Comment: What are you returning? If you are returning only the parent node, the child nodes will be deallocated when the `vector` goes out of scope.

Comment: @PaulG. yes I think that is what happens. Im only returning the parent but hoped the child nodes will stay. Is there are way to do that?

Comment: I think `std::vector<Node> textFunction(std::vector<Node> nodes) ` is your problem.  You build nodes that point into `nodes`, but `nodes` was passed by value, so it an everything inside it goes away when the function ends.  If you use `std::vector<Node> textFunction(std::vector<Node>& nodes)` that might fix your problem.

Comment: so I created a repoducable example, it also shows the correct values when printed inside the function and the wrong values when printed outside the function

Comment: @TheodorPeifer You could have both parent and children in one `vector` and return that vector.

Comment: Storing a pointer you acquire with `&` for later use is rarely a good idea. Both arguments to `createNodeFamily` are destroyed when the function returns.

Comment: I think I found a solution. Instead of assigning the child pointer with & I did it with ```new Node``` and then copied the attributed of the child to that new node. Im really not proficient in c++ haha

Answer (score 1):

Storing pointers to stack variables is generally a recipe for disaster as you've found. When you use `new` the pointers aren't to stack variables anymore (they're being stored on the heap), but still are a bit sketchy since you'll need to make sure to `delete` the pointers when you're done, and there will likely be performance implications since your nodes will be scattered around in memory.

Normally when dealing with vectors with elements that reference other elements, I'll try to store index values rather than pointers. Consider the following:

```
struct Node {
    int value;
    size_t left_index;
    size_t right_index;
};

Node createNodeFamily(size_t child1_index, size_t child2_index, std::vector<Node>& nodes) {
    Node parent;

    parent.value = nodes[child1_index].value + nodes[child2_index].value;

    parent.left_index = child1_index;
    parent.right_index = child2_index;

    return parent;
}
```

then anytime you need to access a node you'd use `nodes[index]` instead of just `*node`.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to not create the pointers using `&` but by creating Node using `new` (changes made inside the `createNodeFamily` function):

```cpp
Node createNodeFamily(Node child1, Node child2) {

    Node parent;
    parent.value = child1.value + child2.value;

    parent.left = new Node;
    parent.left->value = child1.value;
    parent.right->value = child2.value;

    return parent;
}
```